# Building docker image for dart app with local packages

Tags: docker, dart, angular-dart

I am hitting an error when trying to build a docker image and pub get is unable to fined the path to the local package referenced in the pubspec.yaml file. There is no issue with pub get on my local system.

Error:
Because some_dart_project depends on some_local_package from path which doesn't exist (could not find package some_local_package at "../some_local_package"), version solving failed.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/dart-runtime-base) helped me overcome the errors delineated above. It was because my project folder structure didn't match that of the docker file.